Change file during build
I would like to implement CopyWebpackPlugin from Webpack in Vite configuration.
This should amend JSON file properties to another from imported files.
    new CopyWebpackPlugin({
      patterns: [
        {
          from: "src/manifest.json",
          to: path.join(__dirname, "build"),
          force: true,
          transform(content, _path) {
            // generates the manifest file using the package.json informations
            return Buffer.from(
              JSON.stringify({
                version: pkg.version,
                description: pkg.description,
                homepage_url: pkg.repository.url,
                background: isChrome
                  ? { service_worker: backgroundPageName }
                  : { page: backgroundPageName },
                ...JSON.parse(content.toString()),
              }),
            );
          },
        },
      ],
    }),

Is it possible to have it implemented without writing my own plugin?
import { resolve } from "path";
import { defineConfig } from "vite";

const root = __dirname;

type ResourceExtType = "html" | "ts";

function getPathToResource(name: string, ext: ResourceExtType = "html") {
  return resolve(root, "src", "pages", name, `index.${ext}`);
}

export default defineConfig({
  root,
  build: {
    outDir: "dist",
    emptyOutDir: true,
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        popup: getPathToResource("popup"),
        options: getPathToResource("options"),
        devtools: getPathToResource("devtools"),
        newtab: getPathToResource("newtab"),
        panel: getPathToResource("panel"),
        content: getPathToResource("content", "ts"),
      },
    },
  },
});

I checked documentation, but nothing found. Searched for plugins, but found only https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-static-copy, which is not suitable for me, as I am using public folder.
